# While serializing BST why is in-order essential?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I learnt that, to retain the structure of a BST while serialiing it, one needs to store in-order and one of either pre-order or post-order notations of the tree.

What makes in-order notation essential?

Comment: I'm sure one can prove in-order + pre-order or in-order + post-order is needed to reconstruct the BST. But to be honest I'd serialize it with parent / child relations and the data of each node.

Comment: What's the representation you're talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** Rewrote the answer, the previous version was incorrect.

For a *general binary tree* (with unique elements) your statement would be correct. Consider these two inputs (not very prettily drawn ;-) ):

[image]

If you serialize these using in-order traversal, both yield `ABC`. Similar cases exist for the other traversal types.

So why is a combination of in-order and pre-order enough?

The serialized shape of pre-order is `[root][left subtree][right subtree]`. The root is easy to identify, but you don't know where the left subtree ends and the right subtree begins.

Now consider in-order serialized: `[left subtree][root][right subtree]`. You know what the root is (thanks to pre-order), so it is really easy to identify the left and right subtrees.

Note that this is still not enough if the weights are not unique. If in the above example we change `B` into `A`, both trees would yield `[AAC]` for both traversal types.

---

For *binary search trees* deserialization is much easier. Why? Well, every subtree has the property that the nodes in the left subtree are smaller than the root, whereas the nodes in the right subtree are bigger. Therefore, the pre-order serialization `[root][left subtree][right subtree]` can easily and unambiguously be parsed again. So, in conclusion, the person who told you that at least two serialization approaches are needed for a BST was mistaken (maybe he also forgot about the properties of a BST).

Comment: For some reason I thought he meant Java serialization, but this answer lucidly explains how a simple "string serialization" is enough.

Comment: a bit more thorough/clear than my answer ;). thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Storing BSTs in some sort of order while serializing likely makes it simpler to build upon retrieval. Imagine that you have your BST and just pick nodes at random to serialize and store. When retrieving, it will retrieve in the order stored and then after the fact, **something** would have to go through and connect all of the nodes. While that should be possible - all the information is there - it seems unnecessary. Each node is just sort of floating; the deserialization process/program has to maintain a list of all the nodes (or similar) while it walks through the list connecting piece by piece.

On the other hand, if you store them in some sort of prescribed order, it can build the tree **while** reading in each node - it knows where to connect the nodes since they are in order (for clarity: this doesn't imply the next node must be connected to the previously-read node, in the case of adjacent leaves; it's just much simpler to hop up enough levels to the appropriate branch). This should be faster, and potentially use less memory (no list/container while building).